# Order button not working for CGridView when using custom column - yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I've recently added a custom column to my CGridView using the yii's get method to create a virtual attribute. The virtual attribute that I've created looks like this and works as expected.

```
public function getNumIndv()
    {
        // gets the id of the current list 
        $list_id = $this->id;
        // returns the number of recipients with that list id
        return $count = Recipient::model()->count(array("condition"=>"list_id = $list_id"));

    }
```

From there in my GridView I added the custom column "numindv" like so

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'paylist-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'numindv',
        'balance',
        'due_date',

        /*
        'status',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{Manage}',
            'buttons'=>array
            (
                'Manage' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Manage',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("recipient/index", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                ),

            )
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

This works as expected - *almost.* When the user views the form they see three columns "name, balance, and due-date" not lit up. As well, if you click on them they light up and are sorted. 
for numindv however, the column is automatically lit up and does *not* allow individuals to click on it to change the order. Is there something simple that I'm missing here? Why is my grid view treating my virtual column different from the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use sorting in `CActiveDataProvider` by custom column.

You can make `numindv` column header link by using this approach:

```
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
   'numindv' => 'numindv',
   '*' // all other columns
);

$dataProvider->sort = $sort;
```

But you still do not get the desired result, because when you click on the this sorting link it name will be added in SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `recipient` `t` ORDER BY `t`.`numindv`...
```

But your table is no column `numindv`.

I advise you to use a `CArrayDataProvider`.

**UPD:**

You can set sql rules for this sorting:

```
$sort->attributes = array(
    'numindv' => array(
       'asc'=>"numindv asc",
       'desc'=>"numindv desc",
    ),
    '*' // all other columns
);
```

And in `Recipient::search()` method you should add this line:

```
$criteria->select .= ', (/*any SQL request to retrieve the numindv value*/) as numindv';
```

Comment: Two quick questions
1. What do you mean by "using a CArrayDataProvider" are you saying I should try to add a data field inside it that takes numindv? How would one do that? 

2. When you set $dataProvider->sort = $sort where should this be located? In the controller or in side of the GridView?

Comment: 1. You can write SQL query which returns array and based on this array you can create CArrayDataProvider for generating grid. In this case you should get `numindv` value for every row. To achieve this you can use a loop after executing SQL query or append fetching this value in your query. I guess to get `numindv` value by SQL query you  should execute this in select query: `SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `recipient` WHERE list_id = r.id) AS numindv` FROM `recipient` r.
2. No matter where it is located. The only condition - it should be located before of the CGridView widget.